# Not able to push app to IBM cloud through IBM cloud cli

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to push a simple app to ibm cloud from my local folder(cloned from github). But getting error every time I am trying.I tried every way possible by restarting my system couple of times.[image]

edit 1:
if i am not mentioning path I am getting the below error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

command does not look right.... I should start with

cf push appname

Ref:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud/cf_index.html#cf_push

appname is required and is the name of the application that you see on ibm cloud dashboard.

if you want to pass the path use -p option. So command should be:

```
ibmcloud cf push appname -p C:\Dir1\Dir2\...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply..actually I tried the one you suggested .I just want to push the folder to ibm cloud and running the command from the same directory where the folder is .But i dont know I am getting some wired error like some processes are holding up.I tried multiple times restarting system.The error I am getting is : the process cannot use the file because its in use. refer to edit 1 in my question